# Matplotlib plot without whitespace in tkinter frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

Im trying to display a greyscale image (made with matplotlib) in a tkinter Frame. The image itself is displayed, but only with some whitespace between each side of the actual image and the tkinter Frame border. Any ideas on how i can avoid drawing the image with the whitespace?

My code that i currently use:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
        
fig = Figure(figsize=(20, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(self.data, cmap="Greys", interpolation=None)
ax.axis("off")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.frame)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()
```

The code produces this output in the frame:
[image]

This is roughly how it should look like (with better image quality of course, but you get the idea):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the whitespace exists both in the plot and in the GUI, so the problem lies on the matplotlib side. The `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, right=0.99, top=0.99, bottom=0.01)` method can reduce this whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

> fig.add_axes - Add an Axes to the figure.
>
> ```
> rect : sequence of float
>    The dimensions [left, bottom, width, height] of the new Axes. All quantities are in fractions of figure width and height.
> ```

example code,

```py
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5))
"""
fig.add_axes - Add an Axes to the figure.
    rect : sequence of float
        The dimensions [left, bottom, width, height] of the new Axes. All
        quantities are in fractions of figure width and height.
"""
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlim([0, 9])
ax.set_ylim([0, 9])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()

root.mainloop()
```